# Only allowed to post once every forty minutes

Tags: support

Does only being allowed to post once every forty minutes include other SE sites? I was told that I cannot post a question for this reason - but I have not yet asked any questions on this site. What are possible reasons for this?
Also - is this a rule in general on all sites?

*Update - I tried to post this question and again got the message "You can only post once every forty minutes". Does this 'once' overlap with both the meta and regular site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meta question explains what's happening to you:
[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The relevant part for you is:

> Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)
>
> - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes
> - While the limit is waived for users with 125+ reputation on a given site, questions posted on sites where one has 125+ reputation still count toward the rate limit for sites where one doesn't. For instance, if you ask a question on a site where you have 150 rep, you can't ask another question on a site where you have only 100 rep for the next 40 minutes; however, you can ask them in reverse order immediately (first on the 100-rep site, then on the 150-rep site).